# Block a list of IP Addresses on Cloudflare as text file?

Tags: cloudflare

I have a list of IP addresses in a text file. I would like to block them all from accessing my website, via cloudflare's firewall and IP blocking. For example, in my text file, I have

```
34.122.xxx.xxx
173.64.xxx.xxx
67.231.xxx.xxx
... 1000 more rows ...
```

I understand that I can add each of them individually to Cloudflare if I go to `Security > WAF > Tools`, but this seems tedious.

Question:

**Is there a way to add my list as a text file, or as one big chunk?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on some googling I found [this](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/how-to-add-multiple-ip-addresses-to-block-list-at-once/28082) and [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20190917205340/http://ebin.blog/2018/04/cloudflare-api-bash-script-to-block-ip-address-in-firewall) (this is the ebin.blog archived webpage linking to that script pointed by cs-cf, which is currently broken on the first site). The site presents this Python script modified by c.oyler:

```
import re, sys
import requests
fhand = open ('ip_list.txt')
auth_key = '***'
auth_email ='***'
    
headers = {'X-Auth-Email': auth_email, 'X-Auth-Key': auth_key, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

for ip in fhand:
    data = str('{{"mode":"js_challenge","configuration":{{"target":"ip","value": "{0}"}} }}'.format(str(ip.strip())))
    r = requests.post("https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/***/firewall/access_rules/rules",   headers=headers, data=data)
    print ip
    print r.content
```

As an alternative you can follow these steps:

1. Create a new text file and enter the IP addresses you want to block in the following format, one IP address per line:

```
    192.168.0.1
    10.0.0.2
    172.16.0.3
```

2. Save the file with a descriptive name like "blocked_ips.txt".
3. Log in to your Cloudflare account and navigate to the Firewall app.
4. Click on "Tools" in the sidebar and select "IP Access Rules".
5. Click on "Create Rule" and select "Block".
6. In the "IP address or range" field, click on "Upload a file" and select the "blocked_ips.txt" file you created.
7. Choose a descriptive name for the rule and click on "Save and Deploy" to apply the rule to your website.

Cloudflare will now block all traffic from the IP addresses listed in the "blocked_ips.txt" file.

I have not tried any of the methods, so make sure to back up your settings first.

Comment: So the first idea is to hit their API once per IP? It's a nice answer, but not 100% aligned with the question. The second answer is much more aligned to the question so I have accepted.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how I see it, hitting their API once per IP.